# PHP filtering not working consistently with stash

Tags: stash, solspace-tag

```
{exp:tag:related_entries
    entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
    orderby="relevance" sort="desc"
    limit="10"
    {if '{embed:channel}' != ''}channel="{embed:channel}"{/if}
}

<?php if (!in_array('{entry_id}', $filtered_ids)) { ?>

    {exp:stash:append_list name="my_list" parse_tags="yes"}
        {stash:id}{entry_id}{/stash:id}
        {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
        {stash:item_category}{categories}{category_name}{/categories}{/stash:item_category}
        {stash:item_category_url}{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}{/stash:item_category_url}
        {stash:item_channel_name}{channel_name}{/stash:item_channel_name}
        {stash:item_channel_name}{channel_name}{/stash:item_channel_name}
        {stash:item_hero}{hero}{/stash:item_hero}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}

<?php } ?>

{/exp:tag:related_entries}
```

Why is the above not filtering entries, when the code below works as expected:

```
{exp:tag:related_entries
    entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
    orderby="relevance" sort="desc"
    limit="10"
    {if '{embed:channel}' != ''}channel="{embed:channel}"{/if}
}

    <?php if (!in_array('{entry_id}', $filtered_ids)) { ?>

    do display - {entry_id} 

    <?php } else { ?>
    do not display - {entry_id} 
    <?php } ?>

{/exp:tag:related_entries}
```

I'm trying to filter entries, I have a list of entries that I dont want to display, which I've converted to an array, but when I add the stash append_list code it contains all the entires, even those that will get printed as 'entry_id do - not display' when I run the first code.

Comment: This smells like a parse order issue.  https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/templates/template_engine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is interested, I solved this by hacking the Tag module (which is very nicely written) and added an 'exclude_ids' parameter to the 'related_entries' tag, which when set, filters out the provided ids from the results.

```
    if (ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('exclude_ids'))
    {
        $exclude_ids = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('exclude_ids');

        $filtered_list = rtrim($exclude_ids, '|');
        $filtered_ids = str_replace("|", ",", $filtered_list);

        $sql .= " AND te1.entry_id NOT IN ($filtered_ids) "; 
    }
```